# what filter to use for highly fluctuating data

Tags: filter, signal-processing

I have the following data collected from a heart rate sensor.[image]

The data is in **bpm vs. milliseconds**. All the data points **below 80 is incorrect (errors/noise)**. When it plummets below 80, it's because the heart rate sensor fell off the subject.

Similarly, although on this graph it is not there, there are often spikes that go as high as 500. Those **high peaks are caused by something physically tapping the heart rate sensor.** The **rate should ideally be between 100-160.** However, I'm not sure what filter to apply to correctly display this data.

I tried applying a 100 point median filter. This got rid of majority of the low and high peaks. However, I was told that this removes too much of the detail and that I should use an average filter so that it more accurately describes the data. My argument against this is that \$\frac{100 + 0}{2} = \frac{50+50}{2} = 50\$. Many different values can give me the same average.

I do not come from a DSP background. Hence, how should I proceed? Are there other types of filter that will more accurately let me display this data? Ideally, I'd like to keep the general trend, but not include the sudden dips(any data that dips below 80) and spikes(any data that shoots above 200bpm).

Comment: The best solution really depends on what you are doing. For example, if you are designing a heart rate monitor for use in a hospital, you may want to sound an alarm when the heart rate drops to zero. But if not, why not just discard all the points less than 80 and greater than 500? And/or, continue to use a median filter, but instead of 100 points, use fewer points. Maybe 49 points or 25 or 13 or 5. It is hard to tell from the graph, but it looks like most of the dropouts to zero are for a single point only.

Comment: A filter is not 'for the data'; it's for the significant signal in the data.   What information will be extracted from the data?

Comment: Are those measurements from a real heart? Then your heart rate sensor seems to have some issues, as the heart rate seems to change from around 80 to 140 bpm multiple times while the data only covers 10 seconds. Also the reading changes way to often than it should, considering that a human usually wont reach even 4 real heartbeats per second. At the moment I would worry about the sensor rather than the filter.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the general advice is to fix the sensor first. Will do. In the meantime, should I delete this post as it is useless in its current state?